# Why is my loop not going infinite

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{

    int n;
    printf("Please give me an integer greater than zero!\n");
    n=GetInt();

    if(n<0)
    {
    printf("You are giving me a bad value!\n");
    return 1;
    }


    for(int i=n-1;i<n;n--)
    printf("%d\n",n);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to know why the loop is not going to infinity if the user enters in a number for `n`. Lets say that the user puts in 40 for `n`; wouldn't `i` always be `n-1`, so 39 and `n` being 40, then `i` becomes 38 when `n` becomes 39 and so on — so wouldn't that make an infinite loop?

Comment: Why does "i become 38 when n becomes 39"?

Comment: `i` is is smaller than `n` only for the first iteration of the loop. After that `n` is decremented and is now equal to `i`.

Comment: In the style of The Crocodile Hunter... "That's not an infinite loop. *That's* an infinite loop." Just imagine I just pulled out a `while(1)` before the second sentence.

Comment: You seem to think `i=n-1` happens at every iteration. But it only happens the first time.

Answer (score 14):

`for(int i=n-1;i<n;n--)`

Lets draw a (really short) table for `n = 40`:

```
  i  |  n
-----+-----
 39  | 40    i < n ? true
 39  | 39    i < n ? false
```

Thus, we'll exit the loop after the 1<sup>st</sup> iteration.

**Clarification**:

I guess you're confused because you think that `i` is updated in each iteration, but that's the point - it **doesn't**, its value is fixed and only `n` is changing.

Comment: This is incorrect. Only one iteration happens - see my anser, or Floris' answer.

Comment: That's what I said :(

Comment: Your answer currently says "we'll exit the loop after the 2nd iteration", but we'll actually exit the loop after the first iteration.

Answer (score 7):

This loop only runs once. Consider:

```
 for(int i=n-1;i<n;n--)
```

- With `n == 40`, on the first iteration, `i = 39`.
- The condition `i < n` is true (`39 < 40 == true`), so we go in to the loop for the first time.
- At the end of the first loop, `n` gets decremented to 39
- The condition `i < n` is false (`39 < 39 == false`), so we don't get a second time through the loop.

---

Now, what happens if we make `n` increase instead of decrease? Will that run forever?

```
  for(int i=n-1;i<n;n++)
```

The answer is "maybe, but probably not":

- Eventually, `n` will reach the largest value that can be stored in an integer, `INT_MAX` (defined in `limits.h`, and on my system it is 2,147,483,647).
- Making an integer larger than `INT_MAX` causes [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).
- The result of integer overflow on a signed integer is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means the result could be anything (and indeed, your program could crash).

On most systems, however, the value will probably wrap around to `INT_MIN`, or -2,147,483,648.

- If this happens, `i < n` will be false, and your loop will terminate.

But, since integer overflow on signed integers is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you can't be sure that this will happen. It is better to write your program to avoid this situation.

---

If you really want it to run forever - just write:

```
while(1) { ... }
```

or

```
for(;;) { ... }
```

These two loops have the advantage that they are common ways to write an infinite loop, and so they are easy for other programmers to read.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `i` is never decremented, so it does only 1 loop:

```
 i=39 n=40
 i=39 n=39  -> stop
```

In order to decrement also `i` you should write:

```
 for(int i = n-1;i<n;n--,i--)
```

Answer (score 2):

`n` will underflow somewhen because int is **signed** and has a value range of -2147483648 to 2147483647 for example (x86).
Somewhen n will get more positive than i.

**Edit:**
The loop has at most 1 iteration.

**Edit 2:**
The loop would have no iterations if n would have the value -2147483648 for example because -2147483648 - 1 will make the value positive (two complement integer arithmetic). But this could never the case because the pre condition is that n may not be negative.

Comment: Look more closely at the loop - it only runs once before the exit condition `i<n` returns false?

Comment: See the answers from Maroun Maroun or trippino for details on why the loop doesn't run for long enough to underflow

Comment: Wrong answer, this loop only executed one time not more!

Comment: @bkausbk : At start `n` has a positive value then `underflow` is not possible

Comment: Ok you are right , if input value is greater zero than this case will never happen.

Answer (score 2):

i is only ever set once at the start of the loop. For example if the user enters 10 then i is 9 for the 1st iteration. By the 2nd iteration n is decremented by 1 and i is still 9.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop:

```
for(int i=n-1;i<n;n--) {
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

Translates into the following `while` loop:

```
{
    int i = n - 1;
    while (i < n) {
        printf(%d\n", n);
        n--;
    }
}
```

The first clause of the `for` statement performs initialization. It is not repeated at each iteration, but only once. Thus, `i` never changes value, and so the loop ends after a single iteration.

Comment: I like this comparison with the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are decrementing `n`. At the second iteration `i < n` is false, you are exiting from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What will happen is:

```
//Example n = 100
for (int i = 100 - 1; 99 < 100; 100--)
//We now have 99 < 99 on the next loop
//After that you will have 99 < 98 etc.. it will only run once
```

To make the loop you want use:

```
for(int i = n-1; i > n ; n--)
```

To make an endless loop use:

```
for(;;) //or while(true)
```

Comment: That's still not infinite.

Answer (score 1):

your condition is wrong in the for loop..in your loop i is not changing only n is changing
try this

```
   for(i=n-1;i<n;i--)
   {
   printf("%d\n",i);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

you written perfect for loop...
for(int i=n-1;i

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;;)
    {
        printf("%d",i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or you can do anything else....
to put in infinite simply make ;; in the other two condition in loop.